# Need simplified logic in using loops for commom context

Tags: c

my question is simple and stupid basics please excuse me.

I have a code like :

```
#define num 8
if (clock_mhz == 80)
{
    for(i = 1, i < num; i++)
    {
        uint32_t temp_divisor = div_coefficient * bitrate;
        temp_brr = (clock_mhz + (temp_divisor - 1)) / temp_divisor;
        BRR = temp_brr - 1;
        divisor = i;
        result = 1;
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    for(i = 0, i < num; i++)
    {
        uint32_t temp_divisor = div_coefficient * bitrate;
        temp_brr = (clock_mhz + (temp_divisor - 1)) / temp_divisor;
        BRR = temp_brr - 1;
        divisor = i;
        result = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

I tried to add some logic to work on this as below but is is asking to end for loop with `;`

```
#define num 8
if(clock_mhz == 80)
{
    for(i = 1 , i < num; i++)
}
else
{
    for(i = 0, i < num; i++)
}
{
    //Code under any one for loop based on condition
}
```

Please help me in making this simple and smart code.

Comment: I tried using macros but seems it doesn't work because I will get clock_mhz in runtime ,tried code is as below sample.
#define CLOCK clock_mhz
#if(CLOCK == 80)
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
printf("In if\n");
#else
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
printf("In else\n");
#endif

Comment: Common logic can be separated into another function that you may mark as inline. Note that #defines are only available after their line.

Comment: If the typo is the only issue, perhaps the question should be closed, if not, than fixed and re-phrased by the OP?

Answer (score 2):

Your loops are identical (unless I missed something) apart from the initial value of `i`.  You may merge them:

```
int initi;

if (clock_mhz == 80)
    initi = 1;
else
    initi = 0;

for (i = initi; i < num; ++i) {
    /* loop as before */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=1;i<num;i++)
```

instead of

```
for(i=1,i<num;i++)
```

Comment: Sorry for typo its for(i=1;i<num;i++) in my code which I used.